# How can I only show warnings if there are no errors?

Tags: compiler-errors, rust, compiler-warnings, rust-cargo

Often during development, I have a bunch of unused imports and variables. I like to fix those *after* I have correctly working code. The warnings these generate cause me to scroll though the `cargo build` output to find errors among all the warnings.

Is that possible to only show the warnings if compilation succeeds?

I don't want to *ignore* the warnings entirely, since I do want to solve them before committing the code.

Answer (score 13):

You can suppress warnings in your compilation using the `-Awarnings` flags. If you use Cargo, you can add it with:

```
cargo rustc -- -Awarnings
```

That will compile your crate with warnings disabled, so only errors will show up. When you get a successful compilation, you can switch back to:

```
cargo build
```

And your crate will compile again (because the flags have changed, the target is no longer up to date) and you will get the detailed warnings.

You can try automating them by running:

```
cargo rustc -- -Awarnings && cargo build
```

This has the drawback of compiling the crate twice if there are no errors and that can take some extra time.

If you want to compile all the dependencies without the warnings, you can run instead:

```
RUSTFLAGS=-Awarnings cargo build
```

But then, the double compilation issue is quite more relevant.

---

As as side note, I think that some IDEs (VSCode?) are able to do that: sort the compiler messages and filter out the ones you are not interested in.

Comment: You may use `cargo check -- -Awarnings`? I haven't tried, but it can save you some time.

Comment: @hellow: I tried, but unfortunately `cargo check` is not able to use `rustc` flags... at least I don't know how. You can use it with the `RUSTFLAGS` trick, though.

Comment: To those working on a workspace, I used `cargo rustc --package [package name] -- -Awarnings`. `--package` can be shortened with `-p`

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for:

```
cargo install cargo-limit; cargo lcheck
```

See https://github.com/alopatindev/cargo-limit/blob/master/README.md for more information.

Comment: Please be more descriptive of the question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).